# Apache Procrun - stop command not working

Tags: java, apache, procrun

I'm having an issue with the "Apache Deamons Procrun" software.  The start command works great and kicks off the program. The stop command always says "Could not find or load main class" except the class the stop command kicks off is the same class that is kicked off to start the program.  All the stop command does is drop a control in a folder the program is watching.

Is procrun smart enough to know that if the java process ends, it will shut down as well? i'm having some issues with that as well sometimes.

Thanks,

Comment: Is your Java app in the form of a Jarfile? If so, does the app run properly when invoked using java -jar [jarfile] (etc)? If so, it's very likely that the classpath given to procrun isn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your stop method has a different signature or your class path may be off. You need to show the command you used to install it and how you have implemented start/stop methods.

I have found a [link](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s2/note/7d64c8aa-e9b8-4b3a-b6c3-0b624d5aad98/jduprey/shared#b=51cbe500-2754-45ff-8608-658f66ab1a2c&n=7d64c8aa-e9b8-4b3a-b6c3-0b624d5aad98) saved in Evernote for a now defunct blog that may help you.